# Content showing PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a problem in a file : movies.php

I want to show all movies on the files when there is no id, and if the id exists, i want to show the movie with that id , i used :

```
echo "<div id='head'>$title</div>";
echo "<div id='bodyar'>$content</div> <br />
          <hr>Category  : <span class='date'>$moviecategory</span></hr>
          <hr>Views : <span class='date'>$views_numimg</span></hr>
          <hr></hr>          <br />"; exit;}
$orderposts = mysql_query("select * from movie ");
echo "<div class='bodypanelposts'>";

while ($rowar = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderposts)) {
    $id_po = $rowar['id'];
    $picture = $rowar['picture'];
    $title = $rowar['title'];
    echo "<div id='movieall'><table id='classing' border='0' 
    cellspacing='2'><tr>      <td>";
    echo "<a href='movies.php?id=$id_po'><img src='$picture' alt='$image_caption' width='180' height='250'><br /></div><div class='movies'>$title</div></a><br />LIKE BOX GOES HERE</tr></td></table></div>";
}
```

The problem is , after using that , the footer is not appearing anymore .. 
I want it to appear.

[image]

Comment: Where is the footer in your code?

Answer (score 0):

To let PHP know it has to start interpret the code, you need start tags:

```
<?php
// PHP code here

?>
```

You should also concat variables by a dot instead of putting into the quotes:

```
 echo "<div id='head'>" . $title . "</div>";
```

*(Some might say this is not important but it is IMO, PHP can't handle it properly in every case.)*

When using `exit;`, you tell PHP to quit and flush the result to the browser.

There is also a closing `}` bracket after the exit, but I don't see any opening `{` bracket.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle your HTML is to do it like this:

```
<div id='head'><?=$title?></div>
<div id='bodyar'><?=$content?></div>
<br />
<table>
    <tr><td>Category</td><td><span class='date'><?=$moviecategory?></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Views</td><td><span class='date'><?=$views_numimg?></span></td></tr>
</table>
<div class='bodypanelposts'>

<?php
while ($rowar = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderposts)) {
    $id_po = $rowar['id'];
    $picture = $rowar['picture'];
    $title = $rowar['title'];
    echo <<<HTML
<div id='movieall'>
    <table id='classing' border='0' cellspacing='2'>
        <tr><td><a href='movies.php?id=$id_po'><img src='$picture' alt='$image_caption' width='180' height='250'><div class='movies'>$title</div></a>
                <br />LIKE BOX GOES HERE
        </td></tr>
    </table>
 </div>
HTML;
?>

</div>
```

Notice the `<?=` tags to do inline PHP echo statements, allowing you to write HTML without having to wrap them in `echo` statements.

You can also use `HEREDOC` syntax to echo out a large chunk of HTML with variables inline.

These two methods make it much easier to reason about what your code is outputting.